# Restore Python3 Install on Mint (Ubuntu) Linux -- import json

Tags: python-3.x, linux, package

I screwed up my python3 disto on Mint Linux 20.
The `json` package that is part of the python distro is missing or unrecognized.
Here is what happens in a console:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json;print(json.__file__)
None
```

There is no code that could be replacing the value of `json` that I can see.
I've tried uninstalling parts of python3 with `apt` and reinstalling, but none of that has solved the issue. How do I unbork my py3 install?

**UPDATE**
I looked at the internal dictionary of the `json` module. Here it is:

```
{'__name__': 'json', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'json', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x7fa82972ad90>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='json', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x7fa82972ad90>, submodule_search_locations=_NamespacePath(['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/json', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/json'])), '__file__': None, '__path__': ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/json', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/json']}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

My ignorance of the Unix file structure is partly to blame.

The python libraries are kept in `/usr/lib`, but changes or additions to them are stored in `/usr/local/lib`. Reinstalling with `apt` only affected the contents of my `/usr/lib` directory.

There was garbage in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` that caused issues. I deleted everything in that directory and that solved the problem. You could probably delete only `json_extensions` in that directory and still fix the problem.

PS: You never want to `apt purge` a python installation. The system depends on python and your OS will literally stop working. I did that a couple of years ago and could not even reinstall python afterwards. I had to reinstall the entire Linux OS.